# Using multiple routes with fastcgi nginx and docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to configure my nginx with fastcgi to point to multiple docker php containers, and I'm not sure in how to format the nginx.conf at the moment I've got / route pointing to one of the services. How can I change that this process would go to /auth and other could go to /profiles

I've tried using upstream but that didn't seem to work with php

```php
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ ^/auth.+\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass auth-ms:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to have seperate routes pointing to other docker containers so for example localhost/auth -> auth container 
localhost/profiles -> profiles container, what's the best way to implement this with fastcgi or could I set up upstream somehows?

Answer (score 0):

**your container must have built in php-fpm,** you can use https://github.com/jtreminio/php-docker/ and listen to tcp not socket...
then you can config the nginx to

```
location /auth {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass http://auth:9000;
    ...
}

location /profile {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass http://profile:9001;
    ...
}
```

waiting for your feedback...